# AngularJS repeat list with 2 index in a row [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), etc]

Tags: angularjs, list, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my sample List ,

```
$scope.list_element = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

I want to Iterate this List into Multiple Rows,  each Row should contain 2 elements from the List. 
**required output,**

```
1 , 2
3 , 4
5 , 6
7 , 8
9 , 10
```

**i am getting like this,**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I tried this using `ng-repeat` i.e: `ng-repeat="val in list_element"`

```
<div ng-repeat="val in list_element">
    <p>{{val}}</p>
</div>
```

i know this is wrong.. it will give one by one... but i want to iterate 2 values in a row instead one...

Comment: can you add the full tag please? where are those number being printed? add more information

Comment: edited my question check it thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `<p>` tag will create a new line by default each time you execute it. And if you replaced it with anything else such as   or just text inside a div

```
<div ng-repeat="val in list_element">
    {{ val }}
</div>
```

this will output 12345678910

In order to solve it, you can use the special [$odd or $even](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) like this

```
<div ng-repeat="val in list_element tracked by $index">
    <br ng-if="$odd"/>{{ val }}
</div>
```

notice that the `<br/>` will only add a new line to output when it's odd. Adjust it to get the result you are seeking.

Comment: thanks for your help... but my question is not about odd or even.. i want to iterate list into 2 indexes instead one by one.. for eg: if a list contains 10 indexes, if i iterate normally will get 10 rows similarly if i iterate as 2 indexes will get 5 rows, if i iterate 3 indexes will get 3+1 rows

Comment: in your question you wanted the output in 5 rows 2 numbers each row if you want 3 numbers then use the $index <br ng-if="$index % 3 == 0 "/>
not sure though if angular supports iterating on more than one index at a time

Comment: just to make things clear iterating 2 at a time will give you a totally different output something like 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 on each row 
but if you want 2 elements each row you MUST iterate over all the elements, because it won't be language/framework dependent then; it will become a total new different thing to discuss.

Comment: it doesnt based on integer it is just for an example... similarly i want to do for other list

Comment: $odd and $even are not used for the elements its for the iteration number 
as an example from java 
int[] array = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k}
for( int i=0;i<10;i++){
syso(i);
}
the $odd and $even are basically the i (counter)